# Let $f$ be a computable and injective function. Is $f^{-1}$ computable and injective?

Tags: turing-machines, computability, undecidability

So I just started learning about computability, undecidability and Turing machines. And I wonder if:

*Given a computable and injective function $f$, is $f^{-1}$ also computable and injective?*

I don't really know where to start to prove this, any hint or explanation would be appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean by $f^{-1}$? What if $f$ is not surjective?

Comment: If $f$ is surjective, then $f^{-1}$ is automatically a bijection, and it is computable: given $y$, just try all $x$ until you find one such that $f(x) = y$.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. By $f^{-1}$ I mean the inverse function of $f$. I have a question on this: if a function $f$ is not surjective implies not having an inverse? Thanks for the surjective case.

Comment: That's really a question to you. What do you mean by $f^{-1}$ in this context? How is $f^{-1}$ defined? Can you explain what $f^{-1}$ is without using the word *inverse*?

Comment: Oh my bad. Let $A, B$ be languages over an alphabet $\Sigma$, then $f: A \subseteq \Sigma^{*} \mapsto B \subseteq \Sigma^{*}$ then, I guess, the inverse function would be defined as: $f^{-1}: B \subseteq \Sigma^{*} \mapsto A \subseteq \Sigma^{*}$

Comment: The domain of a computable function is usually $\Sigma^*$. If you try to implement my suggestion above, you will need a way to enumerate $A$.

Comment: Thanks. Just to clarify, it would not make sense to take into account the case where the function $f$ is not surjective, right?

Comment: It’s up to you. You decide on the definitions.

Comment: Sorry to bother you, I have a question about your suggestion above. If the domain is infinite is it still computable? Can I still try all $x$ if there are infinite?

Comment: Are you familiar with the technique of [dovetailing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dovetailing_(computer_science))?

Comment: No, I was not until now. So basically it is possible to compute all $x$ from the domain and find the only one such that $f(x) = y$, right?

Comment: Right, that's the idea.